# Best way to add/show additional form fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am hoping for some insight on the best way to accomplish the following. I want to create a form that will allow for more fields to be added when a `+` or `add` button is clicked. So for example the user would fill out a text field lets call it "Description" and then next to it another field called "Unit number". I want to allow for multiple "Description" and "Unit number" fields without submitting the form after each entry,  but for the sake of keeping the site looking "Clean" I don't want there to be several duplicate fields if the user only needs to enter information into one of them. I was thinking about using JavaScript to hide the additional fields by just setting `display:none`. Is this a good/efficient solution? Is there a better solution? I am new to programming so take it easy if you feel this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make your fields and put them in a `div` and then hide it. Use jQuery to `.clone` your first row and then update the field names any time the user clicks an `add` link.

Comment: +1 for jQuery. This will make light work of the task. Well worth learning

Answer (score 1):

You can use a templating library like mustache or handlebars. You can also do this using jQuery. My approach would be to generate new elements on the fly. I won't hide it so that the user can see if he is already inputting duplicate. But if you want to make your markup cleaner, you can also hide the field once the user has already inputted something. So when the user clicks on the add button, you will need to check if the user has actually inputted something, if there is an input, then hide it and then generate a new input again.

If you need a code sample, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some javascript I wrote on my own site awhile ago:

```
 var SITE = SITE || {};

SITE.fileInputs = function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $val = $this.val(),
      valArray = $val.split('\\'),
      newVal = valArray[valArray.length-1],
      $button = $this.siblings('.button'),
      $fakeFile = $this.siblings('.file-holder');
  if(newVal !== '') {
    $button.text('File Chosen');
    if($fakeFile.length === 0) {
      $button.after('<span class="file-holder">' + newVal + '</span>');
    } else {
      $fakeFile.text(newVal);
    }
  }
};
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<span class=\"file-wrapper\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"screenshot[]\" id=\"screenshot\" /><span class=\"button\">Choose a screenshot</span></span>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
          $('.file-wrapper input[type=file]').bind('change focus click', SITE.fileInputs);
     }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addss").click(function(){
        addInput("screenshots");
    });
});
```

Then you can just use the array for the name in the php or whatever else you're using to handle the data.

HTML:

```
<div id="screenshots">
     <span class="file-wrapper">
           <input type="file" name="screenshot[]" class="screenshot" />
           <span class="button">Choose a screenshot</span>
     </span>
</div>
<input type="button" id="addss" value="+Screenshot" class="btn" />
```